# Spring oAuth2 with JWT using different authorization and resource servers

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

So I currently have this POC that I'm tinkering right now. I was thinking if it was possible that I can implement a Spring oAuth2 with JWT with a Authorization Server and a Resource Server both in different projects?

Flow goes like this User gets a token or passes through the Authorization Server and as long as he has the token and it's not expired he can make requests on the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the usual way to implement that. You have one authorization service providing tokens, either itself is backed by a database containing user information or maybe is  asking another user service if the credentials are valid. The returned tokens can be used to make authorized request against the resource service(s).

Maybe take a look at the grant flow [here](https://www.google.de/amp/blog.monkey.codes/how-to-use-jwt-and-oauth-with-spring-boot/amp/).